# Update/change order number in a DIV when changed using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has a `DIV` section which is `drag and drop`.  Each `DIV` is in a `for` loop (well will be once the back-end DEV sort it out, for now its just hardcoded).

**HTML**

```
<div class="row sortableRows">
    <div name="orderNumber" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">1</div>
    <div name="startTime" class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">08:00</div>
    <div name="endTime" class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">17:00</div>
    <div name="weekDays" class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">Mon - Fri</div>
    <div name="monthDays" class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">01 - 20</div>
    <div name="months" class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">Jan - Dec</div>
    <div name="goTo" class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">Working hours</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var sortableRows = function () {
    if (allowedSort) {
        $('#sortableRows').sortable({
            disabled: false,
            update: function (event, ui) {
            //     var Newpos = ui.item.index();
            //     alert("You moved item to position " + Newpos);
            //     $('span[name = orderNumber]').text(Newpos);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Stops drag & drop when clicking 'Add' button
            $('#sortableRows').sortable({
                disabled: true,
            });
        }
    }
```

**Image**
[image]

So what i'm after as an example is if postion 1 is moved to 3 then the following

Position 2 becomes 1
Position 3 becomes 2
Position 1 becomes 3
and so on and so on

But i can't for the life of me figure it out in `JQuery`.  I know this code needs to go in the 'Update' part of my `function` call.

If I un-comment the `alert` in the 'Update' part of the `function` I get the below:

[image]

Which is fine but the issue i also have is that the 'First' row can NOT be moved so its from the second row on wards so the `index` needs to start at '1' and NOT '0' also.

The following line of code `$('span[name = orderNumber]').text(Newpos);` updates all my numbers but this is because they all have the same `name` as this list will be populating each `row` with a uinque `id` (numbers in blue was the original number).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-number the rows after a move, I would suggest you to use an `.each()` loop:

```
$('span[name = orderNumber]').each(function(index){
  $(this).text(index+1);  // Loop index is used
});
```

So the loop index is used to re-number all the rows. That is zero-based too... But notice the `+1`.